# Moved a directory to a non-existing location?

Tags: data-recovery, mono

I used MonoDevelop to write a small `C#`-program that moves directories and files from one location to another location, but I messed it up a bit.

I used C#'s `DirectoryInfo.MoveTo(path1, path2);` to move the folder, but I forgot to specify the actual parent folder of `path2`.

The initial situation was like this: I have a subfolder in the folder `/home/waka/Downloads/folder/subfolder_Name_That_Is_Too_Long_For_My_Liking`

I tried moving/renaming that subfolder to simply `/home/waka/Downloads/folder/subfolder`, but didn't specify the `/home/waka/Downloads/folder` part and instead moved it like this:

`DirectoryInfo.MoveTo("/home/waka/Downloads/folder/subfolder_Name_That_Is_Too_Long_For_My_Liking", "subfolder");`

So, my question is: Where did this folder end up? I can't use `history | grep mv` because I didn't use the `mv` command. Did I just delete the folder or is it still somewhere to be found?

What I have tried:
1. Running `fsck`, but this warns me that on mounted devices I will damage the file system.
2. I tried simply reversing the blunder, but got a `Directory not found` exception.

Comment: You might consider searching for files modified in the last N minutes: https://stackoverflow.com/q/14032188/1101509

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's under the directory that was the current working directory of the Mono process that executed the move.